# Apache mod_rewrite is enable on server but not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have recently installed the lamp stack and have enabled mod_rewrite:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
$ service apache2 restart
```

I can see it on my phpinfo:

[image]

But when I try to access an URL like this below in my WordPress:

```
http://my-localhost/my-wordpress/whats-on/
```

I get this error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /my-wordpress/whats-on/ was not found on this
>   server.
>
> Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80

What else can I do? Have I missed anything?

Any ideas?

I have my .htaccess on too:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my-wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /my-wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But why?

**EDIT:**

I created a simple test:

```
RewriteRule ^test.html$ test.php [L]
```

But i get 404 error instead of being directed to test.php

```
Not Found

The requested URL /mod_rewrite/basic/test.html was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.1.1 Port 80
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe the .htaccess file is being ignored? Start by adding a simple rewrite rule Like: RewriteRule ^test.html$ test.php [L] and make sure you create a test.php file.

Comment: @OfirBaruch yes i think u r right. just tested with ur suggestion and I get 404 error instead of being directed to test.php so how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you set `AllowOverride all` in your main config?

Comment: @cen aww I didn't! works now. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked file permissions? And http_host in image is 127.0.1.1 not 127.0.0.1. Was that on purpose?

Comment: @sadlyblue I forgot to set `AllowOverride all`. Now works. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To fix this issue follow this:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Find:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Replace With:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Exit and save and restart apache with command

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

THE END :-)