# Htaccess issue with RewriteOptions InheritBefore

Tags: apache, .htaccess, inheritance, mod-rewrite

I have got two htaccess:

*api/public/.htaccess*

```
RewriteRule . index.php
```

*api/public/cron/web/.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
```

I set my vhost for cron:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName cron.api.local
    ServerAlias www.cron.api.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/api/public/cron/web
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api_cron_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api_cron_access.log combined
    <Directory "/var/www/api/public/cron/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Url http://cron.api.local/up returns 404 status but when i replace `RewriteOptions InheritBefore` with `RewriteRule . index.php` then it works. What is wrong?

I use apache 2.4.18 and ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue follow this:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Find:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted </Directory>
```

Replace With:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Exit and save and restart apache with command

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Reverence:
[Apache mod_rewrite is enable on server but not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921034/apache-mod-rewrite-is-enable-on-server-but-not-working)